# is it possible to to remove MULTIPLE subscribers from running journey?

Tags: javascript, journeybuilder, automationstudio, unsubscribe, remove

Hey if i have a running journey and im receiving a DE with subscribers that i have to Remove from the journey. is there a way to do that ? if so is there a specific script ?